# Adding Multiple string values

Tags: c++, string, templates, concatenation

I have this function that gets 3 input(mostly LPCSTR) and combines them together and finally return the value:

```
template<typename T>
inline T  const& LPCombine(T const& lpStr1, T const& lpStr2, T const& lpStr3)
{
    std::string str1, str2, str3, Combined;
    LPCSTR lpCombiend = "";

    str1 = lpStr1;
    str2 = lpStr2;
    str3 = lpStr3;

    Combined = str1 + str2 + str3;

    lpCombiend = Combined.c_str();

    return lpCombiend;
}
```

If I print the value of `lpCombined` in the same function it's correct and strings or numbers are concatenated so well but If I print the returned value from the `LPCombine` function from another function like the **main** function the printed value is something weird and unreadable:

> ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

What is the problem?

Comment: @Chiel That isn’t good enough; often `T` would itself be a pointer type, which would have the same problem.

Comment: @Chiel The result of `c_str` is only guaranteed to last as long as `Combined`, so it gets `delete`d after the end of the function as `Combined` itself is being destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `T == LPCSTR`, i.e. `const char*`, your function returns const reference to a raw `char` pointer.

The main problem is that this pointer points to the memory of a `std::string` object (`Combined`) defined *inside* the function body:

> ```
> std::string ..., Combined;
> ...
>
> lpCombiend = Combined.c_str();
>
> return lpCombiend;
> ```

(Note that you seem to have a typo, `lpCombiend` should be `lpCombined`.)

When the function terminates, the `Combined` `std::string` object is destroyed, so the `lpCombiend` pointer points to garbage.

In particular, using Visual C++ in debug builds, uninitialized memory is marked with `0xCC` byte sequences. Note that 0xCC is the ASCII code 204 = `╠`(Box drawing character double line vertical and right), which is exactly what you have in your output.

So, you should consider returning a `std::string` object instead.

I'd also question the declaration and design of your template function. Does it really make sense to have `const T&` input string parameters? If `T` is e.g. `PCWSTR` (`const wchar_t*`), the `str1 = lpStr1;` assignment inside your function body won't work, as `str1` is a `std::string`, and you can't create a `std::string` from a `const wchar_t*` raw pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Combined is destroyed on exit from LPCombine function. As result, LPCombine returns pointer to freed memory and you have unexpected behavior. Maybe you need to return std::string from the function (use std::string as input parameters).

Comment: Yes, using a template for this is not a good idea in the first place, since you cannot implicitly cast just anything to a std::string or back.